# How to import and use PyWhatKit on Google Colaboratory?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, whatsapp, sendmessage

I wanted to automate sending messages on WhatsApp from Google Colab using the pywhatkit library. So far I have tried doing:

```
pip install pywhatkit
```

Output:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pywhatkit in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: wikipedia in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pywhatkit) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyautogui in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pywhatkit) (0.9.53)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pywhatkit) (2.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pywhatkit) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: mouseinfo in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pyautogui->pywhatkit) (0.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyscreeze>=0.1.21 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pyautogui->pywhatkit) (0.1.28)
Requirement already satisfied: pygetwindow>=0.0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pyautogui->pywhatkit) (0.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: PyTweening>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pyautogui->pywhatkit) (1.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python3-Xlib in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pyautogui->pywhatkit) (0.15)
Requirement already satisfied: pymsgbox in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pyautogui->pywhatkit) (1.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrect in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pygetwindow>=0.0.5->pyautogui->pywhatkit) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyperclip in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from mouseinfo->pyautogui->pywhatkit) (1.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests->pywhatkit) (2021.10.8)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests->pywhatkit) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests->pywhatkit) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests->pywhatkit) (1.24.3)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from wikipedia->pywhatkit) (4.6.3)
```

I have also tried to see if `pip list` has it installed and it says it has:

```
pip list
```

Output:

```
....
....
pywhatkit     5.3
....
....
```

When I try to import it shows error.

```
import pywhatkit
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-54f6f476dc6e> in <module>()
----> 1 import pywhatkit

4 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/os.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    679         except KeyError:
    680             # raise KeyError with the original key value
--> 681             raise KeyError(key) from None
    682         return self.decodevalue(value)
    683 

KeyError: 'DISPLAY'
```

What is the workaround or solution to this problem?

Comment: `DISPLAY` may means it needs access to GUI on server - `X11`/`XWindows` on Linux` - to display it on monitor connected to server. But servers usually don't have monitors and they don't use GUI (so they don't have it installed) because nobody can see this GUI (except admins). You may try to use fake GUI like [xvfb](https://github.com/cgoldberg/xvfbwrapper)